# Angular 2 http.get

Tags: angular, http-get

I am doing the following get in Angular 2 and I am getting a runtime exception:

```
http.get('http://localhost/MyCart/Home/GetProducts').subscribe(result => {
    this.categories = result.json().Data as any[];
    this.LoadDictionary();
    window.console.log(this.categories);
});
```

Is that the correct syntax? What am I doing wrong? If I delete the http.get, application is fine.

**EDIT:**

The error is below. Keep in mind I am using Angular's SPA template for .NET Core.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: ReferenceError: window is not defined
>   at C:\Users\samir\Desktop\angular-core new\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:269:13
>   at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (C:\Users\samir\Desktop\angular-core new\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:3774:40)
>   at SafeSubscriber.module.exports.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (C:\Users\samir\Desktop\angular-core new\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:23052:16)
>   at SafeSubscriber.module.exports.SafeSubscriber.next (C:\Users\samir\Desktop\angular-core new\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:23001:22)
>   at Subscriber.module.exports.Subscriber._next (C:\Users\samir\Desktop\angular-core new\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:22943:26)
>   at Subscriber.module.exports.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\samir\Desktop\angular-core new\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:22907:18)
>   at EventEmitter.module.exports.Subject.next (C:\Users\samir\Desktop\angular-core new\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:68525:25)
>   at Object.next (C:\Users\samir\Desktop\angular-core new\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:90000:21)
>   at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (C:\Users\samir\Desktop\angular-core new\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:3762:56)
>   at SafeSubscriber.module.exports.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (C:\Users\samir\Desktop\angular-core new\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:23052:16)
>   at SafeSubscriber.module.exports.SafeSubscriber.next (C:\Users\samir\Desktop\angular-core new\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:23001:22)
>   at Subscriber.module.exports.Subscriber._next (C:\Users\samir\Desktop\angular-core new\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:22943:26)
>   at Subscriber.module.exports.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\samir\Desktop\angular-core new\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:22907:18)
>   at EventEmitter.module.exports.Subject.next (C:\Users\samir\Desktop\angular-core new\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:68525:25)
>   at Object.next (C:\Users\samir\Desktop\angular-core new\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:90000:21)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I edited the question and added the error.

Comment: Try replacing `window.console.log(this.categories);` with `console.log(this.categories);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.console.log(this.categories);
```

should be

```
console.log(this.categories);
```